Is there a way to add generated files to visual studio project using python
I am working on generating some C++ code using python scripts.  I figured out that using Properties->Build Events->Pre Build Events I should be able to achieve this. Now i would also like these generated files to be added in my project using some python script or any other automated way. How can i achieve this ?
